# timer.performWithDelay() not returning table on variable reassignment

Tags: lua, coronasdk

### Goal

I have a global variable made to store the table returned by timer.performWithDelay. My goal was, in the scene:show() function for the timer to be cancelled, and recreated with a new delay.

### Problem

I'm getting a nil return value in the variable used to store the table when the timer is recreated.

### Code:

```
local timerVar

local function update()
    print("updating")
    print(timerVar)
    timer.cancel(timerVar)
    timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(delay, timerFunction, 0)
    print(timerVar)
end

function scene:create(event)
    timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(delay, timerFunction, 0)
end

function scene:show(event)
    if (phase == "will") then
        update()
        timer.resume(timerVar)
    end
end

function scene:hide(event)
    if (phase == "will") then
        timer.pause(timerVar)
    end
end
```

Console output:

```
updating
table: 095D9CA8
nil
```

### What's happening here?

Is timer.cancel() removing the the timerVar variable altogether?
If I can't keep the timer, how can I get around this so that I can have the timer table stored under the same name and with the same scope, but born anew?

Comment: This is not about standalone Lua. Please tell us the context Lua runs in here.

Answer (score 1):

I try reproduce your problem but got

```
updating
15:28:47.324  table: 0091F958
15:28:47.324  table: 0772C590
15:28:47.324  WARNING: timer.resume( timerId ) ignored because timerId was not paused.
```

My code:

main.lua

```
local composer = require( 'composer' ) 

composer.gotoScene( 'test' )
```

test.lua

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

local timerVar
local delay = 1000

local function timerFunction()

end   

local function update()
    print("updating")
    print(timerVar)
    timer.cancel(timerVar)
    timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(delay, timerFunction, 0)
    print(timerVar)
end


function scene:create( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view
 timerVar = timer.performWithDelay(delay, timerFunction, 0)
end

function scene:show( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase

   if ( phase == "will" ) then
       update()
        timer.resume(timerVar)
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then

   end
end

function scene:hide( event )
   local sceneGroup = self.view
   local phase = event.phase

   if ( phase == "will" ) then
      timer.pause(timerVar)
   elseif ( phase == "did" ) then

   end
end

function scene:destroy( event )

   local sceneGroup = self.view
end

scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

return scene
```

Try install latest stable version of Corona.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately even with the absolute newest updates of Corona, Windows 8, and VS code (my IDE), the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically a direct answer to my question, but it did solve my problem, so I'll put my workaround here for future users. I was able to avoid cancelling the timer altogether by simply changing the delay of the timer. this is accomplished as simply as:

```
timerVar._delay = newDelay
```

Note the underbar before the delay variable, it's easy to miss.

This allowed me to update the delay without making a new timer.